# Using python to change and run SQL queries

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, automation

I have the following code that creates a dataframe based on user input:

```
import pandas as pd
  from pandas import DataFrame

 publications = 
 pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nkambhal/data/pubmed_search_results_180730.csv", sep= 
 "|")

 publications['title'] = publications['title'].fillna('')

 search_term = input('Enter the term you are looking for: ')

 publications[['title','publication_id']] 
 [publications['title'].str.contains(search_term)]
 title_mask = 
 publications.title.str.lower().str.contains(search_term.lower())
 new = publications.loc[title_mask, ['title', 'publication_ID']]
```

Now I want to use the publication ID's in the new dataframe to run this SQL query:

```
SELECT
   author_profile
   pub_lst.* 
FROM
   pub_lst
JOIN
    author_profile
        ON pub_lst.author_id = author_profile.author_id
WHERE
    pub_lst.publication_id IN (67855,65559);
```

In the where statement, I want the IDs in the new dataframe to be there. So in the data frame there are the publication_ids ( 5, 6, 4) then I want them to be added to the query.

How can I add the appropriate publication_ids to the SQL query and run it through python and save it to a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put data into a string, you can use the python's `str.format` function. You can read about it a little more [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)

For your query string, it should work out like so:

```
query_string = """
SELECT
   author_profile
   pub_lst.* 
FROM
   pub_lst
JOIN
    author_profile
        ON pub_lst.author_id = author_profile.author_id
WHERE
    pub_lst.publication_id IN {};
"""
print(query_string.format(str(tuple(new.publication_ID.values))))
```

As for the running the query, you will need to use a python module for whichever database you want to connect it. Such as `PyMySQL` for connecting to a MySQL database. https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/

Although, you could use an ORM such as [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) or [SqlAlchemy](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy) to make your life a little easier while dealing with SQL databases. Pandas and SqlAlchemy mix really well. But Peewee is easier to get started with.

For creating a csv, you could use the inbuild python `csv` module, `pandas` or `Peewee` or `SqlAlchemy` in ascending order of difficulty.